# android How to disaplay image at a particular place on screen

Tags: android

I am developing a remote desktop application so i am reading the image data from the stream and displaying it on the android device.So is there any way that i can display the image at particular location on the screen.May at a particular x,y coordinates location on the device

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) to display at particular x,y coordinates.

You can find `AbsoluteLayout` examples [HERE](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/02/absolute-layout-tutorial-android-ui.html) and [HERE](http://start-jandroid.blogspot.in/2011/01/android-buttonandroid-button.html)

However I don't really recomment using it. Here's what docs say about `AbsoluteLayout`:

A layout that lets you specify exact locations (x/y coordinates) of its children. Absolute layouts are less flexible and harder to maintain than other types of layouts without absolute positioning.

I would rather use a `RelativeLayout` and specify margins like `layout_marginTop` and `marginLeft` to specify image location in density pixels (dp)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `RelativeLayout`.

See doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)